# Map the URL of non-Javascript resources with SystemJS

Tags: javascript, web-applications, angular, systemjs

My angular 2 app is referring to the language properties files (en.json and fr.json) under folder i18n.

By default, the i18n folder is placed the same location of the index.html in order to be reached. But I need to place i18n in its grandparent folder. How do I configure for this matter?

In my failed attempt, I tried to map the URL from 'i18n' to '../../i18n'

```
System.config({
                defaultJSExtensions : true,
                bundles : {
                    .
                    .
                    .
                    //Javascript resources bundles
                },
                map: {
                    'ng2-translate': 'js/ng2-translate',
                    'rxjs': 'js/rxjs',
                    'i18n': '../../i18n/'
                }               
            });
```

I am not sure if the failure is due to property *defaultJSExtensions : true*.

P.S.
Later on I found similar problem with mapping the path of *ng2-translate* and *rxjs*.

It doesn't make sense but it seems if I try to reach a parent folder in this senario, it will start from the directory of the code that summons it instead of the file where the System.config is located at.

Comment: I don't know about your build-environment but maybe try a relative path by adding `./` to your try like so `./../../i18n/`

Comment: After looking at your question again: I guess the index.html is at the webroot of your application. It is not possible for your webserver to reach a file which is in a parentfolder of your webroot.

Comment: @Riscie  Actually for my case, the grandparent folder of the index.html file is not located in the webroot. So I guess it is still possible to reach the file.

Comment: By the way, the "./" suggestion didn't work for me..